# How to add an unconstrained TextField to a GridPane using SceneBuilder?

Tags: javafx, textfield, scenebuilder, resizable, gridpane

I am trying to use Java FX (in Eclipse).  I am building a GridPane using Scene Builder and want to add a TextField to the GridPane which is freely resizable, i.e. isn't constrained by the grid.  How do I do that?

Comment: Explain *freely resizable*!

Comment: By freely resizable I mean the TextField can assume any size, not necessarily equal to multiples of cell sizes.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say here is that you don't want your TextField to fill the whole available space of one cell in the grdipane and can decrease/increase its size irrespective of the size of the cell. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I want to be able to resize the TextField to, for example, 1.5 times the width of a cell.

Comment: You can just make the *MIN HEIGHT* and *MIN_WIDTH* to *USE_PREF_SIZE*  in Scene Builder and then drag and set whatever width and height you want for your TextField.

Comment: Thanks.  I think you also need to set MAX_WIDTH to USE_PREF_SIZE and then it works.  But even though the width can now be arbitrary, the position still snaps to grid.  Any idea how to make it arbitrary as well?

Comment: Ahh, correct. You cannot arbitrarily move a child inside a gridpane. Though, what you can do is set its *Valignment* and *Halignment* to different values to suit your need.